# Changing color of radiobutton inside jqueryui buttonset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, colors

I have a jquery radiobutton that I have styled with Jqueryui's buttonset:

```
<link type="text/css" href="jqueryUI1.8.16/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryUI1.8.16/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#atable tr").buttonset();


});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="atable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="aspmnr">1</td>
    <td class="aspm">Test text</td>
    <td class="aradio">
      <input id="asp11" name="asp1" type="radio" value=0>
      <label for="asp11">0</label></td>
    <td class="aradio">
      <input id="asp12" name="asp1" type="radio" value=1>
      <label for="asp12">1</label></td>
    <td class="aradio">
      <input id="asp13" name="asp1" type="radio" value=2>
      <label for="asp13">2</label></td>
    <td class="aradio">
      <input id="asp14" name="asp1" type="radio" value=3>
      <label for="asp14">3</label></td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

i want to be able to change the background color of one of the buttons like:

```
$("#asp11").css("background-color","#aaaaa5");
```

I have also tried applying the css to the label but the background color changes back to default in a split second.
I would like to avoid messing with the original stylesheet of the jqueryui.

Anyone have an idea how to change background color of the button?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$(".aradio label").css("background-color","#aaaaa5");
```

```
$(".aradio label").css("background-image","none");
```

OR

```
$(".aradio label:first").css("background-color","yellow");
```

```
$(".aradio label:first").css("background-image","none");
```

OR

```
$(".aradio label").eq(1).css("background-color","red");
```

```
$(".aradio label").eq(1).css("background-image","none");
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot. Since I'm new I cannot vote for you.

Comment: Keep continue asking you problems. Here you find best solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the background image on the label, do all the css code on the label, e.g     
    0

```
$("#lblforasp11").css("background-color", "#aaaaa5");
$("#lblforasp11").css("background-image", "none");
```